# Adjusting table to textwidth

Tags: tables

I have a table that stretches over the total horizontal space of my page. However, I want its length to be equal to the textwidth. I tried some things I found at similar question but nothing seems to work. I included a MWE below.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

In order to get the most complete view of the different methods, their computation times are printed in the table below:

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Computation time for the different bootstrap methods\label{comptimes}}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{l|llll}
&    \textbf{Classical method} & \textbf{SBS robustification}     &  \textbf{Winsorized bootstrap} & \textbf{IFB bootstrap} \\ \hline
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Computation time \\ (in  seconds)\end{tabular}} & 10.28                 & 155.97                     &  40.67                     & 54.31             
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which similar question? What did you try that did not work? Editing the question to include this information will help us to help you. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general answer would be `tabularx`.  But for your use-case, I suggest you re-think the way your table is presented.  What do you think about a solution like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

In order to get the most complete view of the different methods, their
computation times are printed in the table below:
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \caption{Computation time for the different bootstrap
    methods\label{comptimes}}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format = 3.2]@{}}
    \toprule
    Method               & {Time (sec.)} \\\midrule
    Classical method     & 10.28  \\
    SBS robustification  & 155.97 \\
    Winsorized bootstrap & 40.67  \\
    IFB bootstrap        & 54.31  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using `threeparttable\  in order to have capion iwdth equal to caption width, and setting caption font to `\footnotesize` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

In order to get the most complete view of the different methods, their computation times are printed in the table below:

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Computation time for the different bootstrap methods\label{comptimes}}
\footnotesize
 \begin{tabular}{@{}p{.19\textwidth}|p{.19\textwidth}@{}p{.19    \textwidth}@{}p{.19\textwidth}@{}p{.19\textwidth}}
&\textbf{Classical method} & \textbf{SBS robustification} &      \textbf{Winsorized bootstrap} & \textbf{IFB bootstrap} \\ \hline
Computation time (in  seconds)& 10.28 &155.97 & 40.67 & 54.31             
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```